# difference between digital search tree and radix search trie

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, trie

Consider a digital search tree and a radix search trie and a set of N keys that will be inserted into them. Does the order that the keys are inserted affect the shape of the resulting tree?

I think it will affect DST but not RST since DST's nodes are inserted based on their starting bits. If you flip some nodes, the shape of DST will be different.

Is this correct? If not, can you give me some examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does the `tire` tag relate to your question? Did you mean `trie`? In that case you have the spelling mistake everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big drawbacks to a DST is that its not in sorted order. If we want it in sorted order, we would have to extract the data from the tree and sort it.

RST on the other is in sorted order as long as you do in-order traversal similar to a BST.